# Jquery or javascript: dragging an image to a certain position to change pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

im making a one page layout of a website, i would like to ask if it is possible to use a draggable image to a certain position to change pages?

im not that good with jquery and js so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:
     [example](http://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)

if this like you want... it's a [parallax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). so you can try to find a [tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/) to do this.

best regards,